# Are the av_free* functions in ffmpeg idempotent?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, idempotent

Specifically I'm looking at `avformat_free_context`.  In normal execution of my code, `avformat_free_context` is called appropriately.  I would also like to call it in the destructor of a class, in case there was an exceptional case that caused the code using the `AVFormatContext` to return early.  Do the ffmpeg free functions behave appropriately when called on already freed data structures?

Comment: Don't have a definite answer, but that seems extremely unlikely. `free()` isn't idempotent either, and I don't see how anything that is like it could be unless it modifies the handle you pass it. Anyway, why not just remove the `free_context` call from your normal codeflow and rely on the destructor alone? That's the C++ way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, not all of them are.

*Links are to function definitions; see for yourself!*

### `av_freep`

[`avformat_free_context`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavformat_2utils_8c_source.html#l03533) calls [`av_freep`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/mem_8c_source.html#l00235) on some pointers held by the `AVFormatContext` which doesn't perform a `NULL` check before passing the address of the memory to be freed off to [`av_free`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/mem_8c_source.html#l00220) (which is essentially just a call to `free`; see below). It does, however, set the pointer to NULL.

### `av_free`

If ffmpeg was compiled with `CONFIG_MEMALIGN_HACK` defined, `av_free` will do a NULL check before freeing. This will effectively make `av_freep` idempotent for memory which is freed by `av_freep(&pointer_to_data);`. This might not be the case for your build.

### `others`

Additionally, some of the other functions called by `avformat_free_context` are idempotent. They achieve this by clearing pointers and performing NULL checks, or decreasing array indexes to prevent a double free. Examples include [`ff_free_stream`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavformat_2utils_8c_source.html#l03511) and [`av_opt_free`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/opt_8c_source.html#l01410).

### `avformat_free_context`

`avformat_free_context` will perform a NULL check before attempting to free the context. So if you pass NULL to it, you don't have to worry. However, **if you double-free an `AVFormatContext` you *will* end up doing a low-level double-free, because `avformat_free_context` calls `av_free` directly on the `AVFormatContext`.**

### Advice

The safest thing to do when freeing a context is:

```
avformat_free_context(pcontext);
pcontext = NULL;
```